# CiviEvent Blocking iframes?

Tags: civievent, ckeditor

I am trying to embed a youtube video in a CiviEvent page. I have turned off CKEditor's content filtering by following the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221583/ckeditor-allow-video-embed-code). When I add simple embed code to a CiviContribution page, it works. When I do the same with a CiviEvent page, the code never makes it to the page's source code, as though it has been stripped out along the way.

Any idea why these modules would behave differently and what might be causing CiviEvent to block iframes?